# Prevent encoding in url from htaccess using french language

Tags: .htaccess, encoding

I am trying to add RewriteRule to redirect target url. My code is as below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.fr [NC] 
RewriteRule ^accessoires/bouteilles-d-eau/bouteille-el$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/accessoires/bouteilles-d-eau/bouteille-eléphant-370ml.html [NE,R=301,L]
```

Though it works fine and redirects to target url as specified but in browser it changes **é** to %e9

Due to this it gives me 404 error on my site.

How can i prevent this encoding?

I have tried different combination of [NE,R=301,L] but no luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

The B flag might help.  (escape backreferences)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: Still it is not working and redirects with %E9 in url.
I also tried both NE and B flag
RewriteRule ^accessoires/bouteilles-d-eau/bouteille-el$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/accessoires/bouteilles-d-eau/bouteille-eléphant-370ml.html [B,NE,R=301,L]

please guide